# Is there a more elegant way to turn checkboxes into radio buttons?

Tags: javascript

Trying to turn my checkboxes into radio buttons. This works fine

```
ng-change="second=false;third = false;fourth = false;"
```

Here's the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/yTJUZcFoLsSEBjruRuEY?p=preview

Is there a way to make every element in an array false EXCEPT ng-model?

**Example**

`ng-model=myArray[3]`

so `myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[... n]` are all made false 
**EXCEPT** `myArray[3]`, which is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly elegant: [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFjjIEbZXI2v3tqsu9la?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.radio = new Array(4).fill(false)
  $scope.changed = function(el){
    $scope.radio = $scope.radio.map((v,i)=>i==el)
  }
});
```

and html:

```
<div>{{radio[0]}}|{{radio[1]}}|{{radio[2]}}|{{radio[3]}}
  <br/>
  <input ng-repeat="r in radio track by $index" type="checkbox" ng-model="radio[$index]" ng-change="changed($index)"  />
```

Comment: Try `new Array(length).fill(false)`

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that one :)

Comment: You just blew my mind lol. You also taught me .fill(false) with your answer! Thank you... Testing it out now

Comment: Fill is not supported in IE and opera. Be cautious.

Comment: @HassanImam doh! I'm assuming the i parameter is index... Not sure what v is, although it isn't used in the comparison operator of element === index anyway. This solution gets more aesthetic the more I try to understand it. Well done Michal Salacinski!

Comment: @TylerL The solution is really clever. Even I am wondering the same thing.

Comment: "v" is 1'st parameter - value - which isn't really used, but fills the space to use 2'nd parameter - index

Comment: Uh oh... might not be the full solution. Try unchecking 'true' in the plunker. It remains true. Edit: I think it can be fixed with a simple conditional if statement

Comment: That's the exact behavior of radio. But fear not, change one line to $scope.radio = $scope.radio.map((v,i)=>v&&i==el) and it'll let you uncheck everything.

Comment: lol I was going to say "I fixed it" but again with the elegant solutions! Thank you.        if (vm.showPanel[element]){
          return  i==element
        } else {
          vm.showPanel[i] = !vm.showPanel[i];
        }

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried creating changes as per your requirement. See if this work for you.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.checkbox = [false,false,false,false];

  $scope.changeStatus = function(index){
    //fill in not supported in IE and opera
    $scope.checkbox.fill(false);
    //Uncomment and Use this in IE and Opera in case fill throw error
    //for(let i = 0 ; i < $scope.checkbox.length; ++i){
    //    $scope.checkbox[i] = false;
    //}

    if($scope.checkbox[index])
      $scope.checkbox[index] = false;
    else
      $scope.checkbox[index] = true;

    console.log($scope.checkbox);  
  }
});
```

And your HTML code will be

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[0]" ng-click='changeStatus(0)' />
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[1]" ng-click='changeStatus(1)'/>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[2]" ng-click='changeStatus(2)' />
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[3]" ng-click='changeStatus(3)' />
  </div>
</body>
```